# I am new to python and I am seeking for some help. I am trying to run Fama-French for 10 different mutual funds and stuck with it

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am seeking for some help. I am trying to run Fama-French for 10 different mutual funds and stuck with it. 
The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as smf
from datetime import date
import pandas_datareader.data as web

s=date(2017,3,30)
e=date(2020,2,28)
fund='AACIX'

value_funds=[]
growth_funds=[]
#get the data
ff_data=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ff.csv')

def get_returns(fund):
    adj_close=web.DataReader(fund,'yahoo',s,e)['Adj Close']
    fund_rets=adj_close.pct_change()
    fund_rets=fund_rets.dropna()
    returns_data=pd.DataFrame(fund_rets)
    return returns_data

def prepare_data():
    portfolio=pd.DataFrame(get_returns(fund))
    ff_data['fund']=list(portfolio['Adj Close'])
    ff_data['excess']=ff_data['fund']-ff_data['RF']
    ff_data.drop(['fund'], axis=1)
    ff_data.rename(columns={"Mkt-RF":"mkt_excess"}, inplace=True)
    return ff_data

# now run the regression
def run_regression():
    ff_data=prepare_data()
    model = smf.formula.ols(formula = "excess ~ mkt_excess + SMB + HML", data = ff_data).fit()
    print(model.summary())
    return model.params[3]


def sort_funds():
    HML=run_regression()
    if HML>0:
        value_funds.append()
    else:
        growth_funds.append()
    return value_funds
```

How can I loop over multiple tickers in get_returns(fund) function and then perform the regression for each of them?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You're asking how to apply a loop to a sequence -- this is a tutorial issue, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have a list of your funds:

```
funds = ["AACIX", ...]
```

Then in your run_regression function, do this:

```
for fund in funds:
     ff_data = prepare_data(fund)  # Update prepare_data to take an arg
     # etc...
```

Comment: I got it, thanks! But how can I then collect the model.params[3] in a table, where I see the name of the fund and the and the third coefficient (model.params[3])?

Comment: @ivan22 That sounds like another question entirely, no?